# Basic Understanding: Can a computer skip bits/Bytes?

Tags: byte, cpu-architecture, bit, signed, low-level

the last few days I was interested in how a computer works and I want to understand what the PC with CPU, RAM, GPU etc. does (on a low-level) with 0 and 1.

So 8 Bits equals 1 Byte, (e.g. 10100110). My question is: Can a computer "skip" Bits, meaning, jump to the next Byte, based on the first (signed) Bit? I mean, usually a PC processes all Bits of a Byte. If a PC could skip a Byte based on its signed Bit, it would not have to read and process the next seven Bits, and would be in theory faster than if it would process every Bit, expecially with enormous data amounts. I hope you can understand my thought.

For example, if the first Bit is a 0, then process this Byte, if it is a 1, skip this Byte. Or a more useful example, when I have a table with two columns, I could mark the left column with 0s and the right with 1s, and if the left column is not equal to what I search, I skip the remaining 0s, the following 1s and read the next 0s then (the next row of my table).

Is this somehow possible, with a normal PC or a custom self-build? Would that make my processes faster?

Comment: Common hardware these days doesn't address bits directly, they address bytes and they grab a bunch of them at the same time. As for "read and process", that depends on your program and what it does, but those bits have already been read from memory into a CPU register or similar anyway.

Comment: As for "make my processes faster", there's a *ton* of different ways a program can be made faster. Most of which have to do with algorithms, like choosing quicksort or mergesort over bubblesort, that type of thing. After that probably comes optimizations that you can do when you know your programming language in details, and lastly you will have optimizations that will require a thorough understanding of the CPU and related hardware. I would suggest you keep to the first couple of items there, algorithmic optimization and understanding the capabilities of the programming language you're using.

Comment: If you wrote a program that looped over bits of each byte one at a time (e.g. `x>>=1;` / do something with `x & 1`, the low bit), you could optimize it to skip to the next byte based on any early-out condition you like, such as `x&1`, e.g. `test al, 1 / jnz skip_label` in x86 asm.  CPUs just have to be programmable to run software instructions that does stuff.  See Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: I believe that most memory is byte addressable.  You may manipulate bits using assembly or C and many other languages and change the execution of the code by using it.  I would consider reading about systems programming to learn about what you are talking about.  Computer Systems by O'Hallaron is great and really shows you the dirty bits of how our computers work and the value of our nice abstractions.  Do the labs.  They are really cool